# Spacy - [E173] As of v2.2, the Lemmatizer is initialized with an instance of Lookups containing the lemmatization tables

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy

Running Python 3.7.6
Running Spacy 2.3.2

I'm fairly new to Python and especially Spacy. I am unable to import the English language model, no matter what method I seem to try. If I try to import as a module, which seems to be the safest approach, I get the following error.

`import en_core_web_sm`
`nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()`

`[E173] As of v2.2, the Lemmatizer is initialized with an instance of Lookups containing the lemmatization tables. See the docs for details: https://spacy.io/api/lemmatizer#init`

I don't really understand what a Lemmatizer is and was hoping to learn as I go along, but am stuck here. Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Tried using Jupyter instead of Spyder and it's fine...